# All functions in Django settings file are evaluated on exception

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm working with a Django settings file where I've put some functions that I only intend to run in a specific deployment environment. For example, my caching settings differ between production and development -- additionally, my production environment relies on the presence of environment variables that will only be set in productions. When I run my django app in production, I want a KeyError to be thrown if os.environ doesn't contain the env var I want. That's why I'd prefer to use the more conventional `environ['VARNAME']` over the safer `environ.get('VARNAME')`. To achieve this, I've written a function that produces the cache configuration for production (evaluating `environ['VARNAME']`), and if the app detects that it's in production, it runs that function and assigns it to the caches setting.

This works fine until other exceptions in the app eventually develop and occur, and then the django framework seems to evaluate every function in the settings file. This is an annoying problem in development, because the env var keyError occurs when it shouldn't. Does anyone have thoughts as to why django is evaluating functions in the settings file that normally would only be defined and not run?

Comment: I think you'll need to show the code of this function and an example of how it's used.